# Using '/' as greater than less than in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, comparison, operators

I recently got into code golfing and need to save as many characters as possible.

I remember seeing someone say to use `if a/b:` instead of `if a<=b:`. However, I looked through Python documentation and saw nothing of the sort.

I could be remembering this all wrong, but I'm pretty sure I've seen this operator used and recommended in multiple instances.

Does this operator exist? If so, how does it work?

Comment: That's not code golf, that's obfuscation. For golfing `if b>a:` works better.

Comment: It's obfuscation that saves a character, which makes it relevant to golfing.

Comment: `a/b` will *usually* work, but `a>b` will **always** work (even for non-integers - not to mention it's much clearer), so I recommend the latter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> 5/6
0
>>> bool(5/6)
False

>>> 6/5
1
>>> bool(6/5)
True
```

It's a result of the `/` operator in Python 2.7 doing integer division, then converting the result to a boolean.

If you do `from __future__ import division`, this won't work anymore because the `/` operator will do floating point division rather than integer division.

So the result will still be `> 0` for `x < y` and will still evaluate to True.

```
>>> from __future__ import division

>>> 5/6
0.8333333333333334
>>> bool(5/6)
True

>>> 6/5
1.2
>>> bool(6/5)
True
```

Comment: `from __future__ import division` doesn't control rounding per se. It controls the meaning of `/` when operating on integers. Either integer division, or floating point division.

Comment: In python 3, you can use a//b but that doesn't save any characters compared to a<=b

Answer (score 6):

That's just division. And, at least for integers `a >= 0` and `b > 0`, `a/b` is truthy if `a>=b`. Because, in that scenario, `a/b` is a strictly positive integer and `bool()` applied to a non-zero integer is `True`.

For zero and negative integer arguments, I am sure that you can work out the truthiness of `a/b` for yourself.

Comment: Not just positive `a` and `b`, but integer `a` and `b`.

Comment: For positive *integers*. For floats with `a < b`, the result will be 0 point something which isn't zero and hence true.

Comment: If we use integers `a / b` is truthy for every `a` that is not `0` in Python 3.